# Why use the keyword 'const' twice in a class member function C++

Tags: c++, oop, accessor

I keep running across function definitions inside classes that look like this:

```
//Accessor function
const string getName() const {
    return name;
}
```

My question is: why does the word 'const' appear twice. I know the 'const' at the end of the definition helps protect the original member information, but what does the first 'const' do?

Comment: Are you sure it's `const string` and not `const string&`? The latter would make sense, but the former doesn't. It's mostly same as returning just `string`, except it forces the string to be copied instead of moved (which just harms the performance).

Comment: The way I posted it is the way it is written in the book. The book is mostly geared to entry level programs though so I would not be surprised if they are not using the most efficient techniques. They are probably just shooting to get the general point through.

Comment: What's the name of the book? This trick had some use pre-C++11, but these days it's outright wrong, there's zero reason to do it. Either your book is outdated (doesn't cover C++11) or just bad.

Comment: Keep in mind the general rule that the `const` qualifier applies to the thing to its *immediate left*, with the exception that if it appears first then it applies to the thing to its *immediate right*.  The first `string const` return is a string that is const, but that const-ness is immaterial to the caller so is not useful.  The latter `const` applies to the type pointed to by the `this` pointer.  As if the implied `this` were `T const* this`.

Comment: Book is called "Starting Out With C++, From Control Structures Through Objects." The latest edition which I am using was published in 2018 and has many references to C++11.

Comment: @Eljay why would the const-ness be immaterial?

Comment: Because a return-by-value such as `string s = foo.getName();` does not matter that the returned `string` is `const`.

Comment: @Eljay No, this constness is very much material. Among other things, it inhibits moves from the resulting rvalue! You're probably thinking about [`[expr.type]/2`](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.type#2), but it says that prvalues of **non-class** types can't have cv-qualifiers.

Comment: *"has many references to C++11"* Then you found at least one defect in the book. Don't blindly trust what it says.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat • makes sense, thank you for the clarification.  :-)  In *this* case, a `std::string` would be a poor choice to make the result value non-move-able.  But I can think of a few classes in my own project that ought to be copied, and should not be moved.  Well, they *can't* be moved, because they don't have move constructors or move assignment.  But maybe there are some move-able classes where the situation makes sense that the return value needs to prevent moving (possibly to trigger some side-effect).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first `const` qualifies the returned value as non-modifiable; the second `const` specifies that the function does not modify the class instance (or any member of it) on which it was called.

The first is more often used when the function returns a reference to a member, to prevent that returned reference from being used to modify the member to which it refers.

Comment: So if the function were to return a reference to an integer member to the main program, the variable that holds this value in the main program would be unable to change the value? (hopefully I am wording this right)

Comment: @The_Redhawk Yes. If you had `string& str = myClass.getName();` (or some such) in your code, you could modify the `name` member by modifying your returned `str` reference. Adding the `const` qualifier to the **returned** reference will prevent that.

Comment: So in the most basic use, if just need the function to return a person's name so that I can display it on the screen, it would be best to use the first const?