# Why is it not possible to return a const reference while overloading the [] operator

Tags: c++, constants, operator-overloading

Let us take this code as an example

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct valStruct {

    double& operator[](int i){return values[i];};       //line 6
    double operator[](int i) const {return values[i];}; //line 7
    double values[4];
};

int main () {
    valStruct vals = {0,1,2,3};
   cout << "Value before change" << endl;
   for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
      cout << "vals[" << i << "] = "<< vals[i] << endl;
   }

   vals[1] = 2.2; // change 2nd element
 
   cout << "Value after change" << endl;
   for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
      cout << "vals[" << i << "] = "<< vals.values[i] << endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I understand that line 6 (see comment in code) enables the writing (and reading!?) of a value to the index in array `values` while line 7 only reads that value.

I understand the need of the const declaration in line 7 as preventing changing the value while not intended (although I do not understand how since line 6 exists), but my question is, why cannot I write the line as

```
double& operator[](int i) const {return values[i];}; //line 7
```

which throws out the error: `binding reference of type ‘double&’ to ‘const double’ discards qualifiers`.

This also raises the question of why do we need line 7 at all since line 6 exists and can do both writing and reading.

EDIT:

I understand the idea of a const func() const [suggested here][1] and I do not understand how this answers my question. I did not understand the mechanism explained by the two answers given which answer my question.

I now understand that the second line is needed to deal with const objects of my function.

I also understand that when I have a func() const, it implicitly makes the members const. This means that the returned value needs to be constant and that is why this does not work
´double& operator[](int i) const { return values[i]; };´
while this does
´const double& operator[](int i) const { return values[i]; };´
[1]: [Why use the keyword 'const' twice in a class member function C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65635084/why-use-the-keyword-const-twice-in-a-class-member-function-c)

Comment: We need line 7 to work on `const` objects. Line 6 can't be used on `const` objects of type `valStruct`.

Comment: try `const valStruct vals = {0,1,2,3};`

Comment: Because overload from line 7 is chosen when you are operating on `const valStruct`, so `values[i]` is also const and cannot be bound do `double&`.

Comment: @user304584 More info about `const` member function can be found [here](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/const-class-objects-and-member-functions/). There you can also find the statement: *"const class objects can only explicitly call const member functions"* which will help you understand the answer better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why do we need line 7 at all since line 6 exists and can do both writing and reading.

We need line 7 to work on `const` objects. Line 6 can't be used on `const` objects of type `valStruct`. This is because `const` class objects can only explicitly call **const member functions**, and the overloaded `operator[]` in line 6 has not been marked as a const member function. So it can't be used on const object of type `valStruct`. Thus, we need line 7 which "marks" the overloaded `operator[]` as a const member function. More info about this can be found [here](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/const-class-objects-and-member-functions/).

---

Now, if you change the return type in line 7 to `double&`, then the problem is that here you've overloaded `operator[]` as a **const member function**. This means that the data members are also `const`. And since we cannot bind an *"lvalue reference to non-const object"*, to a `const` object, we get the mentioned error. For example,

```
const double d = 43.4;
double& ref = d;//here we'll get the same error
```

The situation(of why you're getting the error) is similar to the above given snippet.

To solve(get rid of) this error, we need to change the return type from `double&` to `const double&`.

Answer (score 2):

`this` refers to a `const` object in `const` qualified member functions. Here:

```
double& operator[](int i) const {return values[i];}; //line 7
```

You are trying to return a reference to `this->values[i];`. That reference cannot be non-const when the object is `const`.

Typically two overloads are provided:

```
double& operator[](int i) { return values[i]; };              // 1
const double& operator[](int i) const { return values[i]; };  // 2
// ^ returned reference is const 
//                                ^ current object is const
```

The first can only be called on non-constant objects. When the object is `const` then the second is called:

```
valStruct a;
double x = a[0];  // calls 1
const valStruct b;
double x = b[0];  // calls 2
```

Because copying a `double` isnt that expensive you can return `double` instead of a reference.

> This also raises the question of why do we need line 7

Because without the const `operator[]` you would not be able to call `b[]`.